# Why Solr match data and count mismatch while using group.limit?

Tags: solr, sunspot-solr, rsolr

I am executing a SOLR Query where I group titles and limit the number of title in groups. The problem I face is I don't get an exact number of matches with the passed limit.

e.g:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=publication,book_code,bookID,book_date,book_images&q=asset_type:Book+AND+AND+engineering:true&group=true&group.field=book_code&group.limit=3&rows=50000&group.sort=book_date+desc
```

How do I convert this query so that I can fetch 10000 records at a time.

Currently the returned result:

```
{"responseHeader"=>
  {"status"=>0,
   "QTime"=>195,
   "params"=>
    {"fl"=>"publication,book_code,BookID,book_date,book_images",
     "indent"=>"true",
     "q"=>"doc_type:Book AND engineering:true",
     "group.limit"=>"3",
     "group.field"=>"book_code",
     "group.sort"=>"book_date desc",
     "group"=>"true",
     "wt"=>"json",
     "rows"=>"50000"}},
 "grouped"=>
  {"book_code"=>
    {"matches"=>30216,
    "groups"=>
      [{"groupValue"=>"NYM",
        "doclist"=>
         {"numFound"=>2683,
          "start"=>0,
          "docs"=>
           [{"book_code"=>"NYM", .... } and so on
```

When I try to retrieve the count of the grouped books I get :

```
result["grouped"]["book_code"]["groups"].count #=> 276
```

Which does not match with the returned matches result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matches` is the total number of *documents* that matched your query. The `["groups"].count` value is the number of distinct groups returned. I.e. the 30216 documents returned belongs to 276 different groups.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Is there any way I can loop over the response and don't pass an Hardcoded value of "rows"=>"50000".

I am unable to find the total records on which I rely on loop count.

Comment: Looping over the response would be however you do that in Ruby; not sure what you're asking about the total number of records - you already have that, and you have the group count (.count)? The row count would matter depending on what you're trying to do, but just giving a high number (if you want all the results) is good enough.